# Access Array with String key

Tags: javascript, json

I have two variables with JSON files. The first is a list of keys looks like this:

```
keylist = ["key1","key2","key3"]
```

The second one is generated from a database and looks like this:

```
data = {
    "key1"{
         #further data
    },
    "key2"{
        #further data 
    },
    "key3"{
        #further data
    }
}
```

Now I want to access the second element of the database with the key from the `keylist`

```
data.keylist[1];
```

Which doesn't work because the return of keylist[1] is a String? I did some research and the use of the window function was proposed. So I tried this:

```
window["data." + keylist[1]]();
```

Which leads to a "is not a function" error. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: use bracket notation: `const res = data[keylist[1]];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As simple as that:

```
const mydata = data[ keylist[1] ];
```

Also, your code is correct from the point of syntax, but it tells completely different than you expect it to tell.

```
data.keylist[1];
```

tells JS that you expect to have an object called `data` which has a property called `keylist` and which is (most likely) type of array, and you want to get the second element of this array.

**PS:** And one more point here. Your question title is not completely correct because of the difference between Arrays and Object in JS.

There is no "string keys" for arrays in JS, so you cannot "access array with a string key". Well, truly speaking there are, but not for items of array. Array items only have numeric index, which you can use to access it. Objects, in contrast to arrays, may have named properties. So when you see something like that: `data = myVar['data']`, you can tell that you're dealing with an object, while `data = someVar[0]` can be both, an Array (most likely) or also an Object with key named '0'.

Comment: This could have been in the comments

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the issue you're having with your first example is because it returns a key. I believe the issue is because `data` doesn't have a property called `keylist`. Instead of that, try it as

```
data[keylist[1]]
```

and see if that works for you. The reason this one should work is that, in this situation, Javascript will evaluate the string return of `keylist[1]` and then use it as a string index for the `data` variable. Let me know if this works out for you :D

Answer (score 1):

You can try using using something like this.

```
data[keylist[1]]
```